# What's the shell session?

Tags: command-line, bash, tty

What's the shell session ?
job seems like a process, is it?
Can one shell prompt can manage multple shell sessions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shell session is your current state/environment in the shell/terminal. You can have only one session in a shell/terminal.

Job is a process which runs in your shell.

You can list all your jobs by entering the `jobs` command.

E.g. when executing some process you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and the previously running process will be suspended. You can then execute such commands as `fg` to bring it back to the foreground, or `bg` to run it in the background.

Answer (score 3):

To see your current shell along with it's process ID, the process ID of parents and the process ID of current command use:

```
$ pstree -aps $$
systemd,1 splash fastboot kaslr
  └─lightdm,1050
      └─lightdm,1294 --session-child 12 19
          └─upstart,1883 --user
              └─gnome-terminal-,10481
                  └─bash,3612
                      └─pstree,15684 -aps 3612
```

- `$$` is the environment variable for the shell's process ID (3612).